# Group, count and concat laps

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, concatenation

I can't resolve this problem (race), I need show the time for each LAP. This is times table

```
 id    | race_id     | car_num | time       |
 +-----+-------------+---------+------------+
 1     | 8           | 25      | 00:09:05   |
 2     | 8           | 33      | 00:09:35   | 
 3     | 8           | 10      | 00:09:55   | 
 4     | 8           | 25      | 00:18:15   | 
 5     | 8           | 33      | 00:19:05   |
 6     | 8           | 25      | 00:39:45   |
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
    car_num, COUNT(car_num) as laps, race_id, concat(vlap,'-',time) as times
FROM
    (SELECT num_car, concat(time,'-',v1) vlap 
     FROM tiempos) vti
GROUP BY 
    car_num
```

This is output required:

```
 car_num    | laps     | race_id | times                                        |
 +-----+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
 25         | 3        | 8       | lap1 00:09:05, lap2 00:18:15, lap3 00:39:45  |
 33         | 2        | 8       | lap1 00:09:35, lap2 00:19:05                 | 
 10         | 1        | 8       | lap1 00:09:55                                |
```

I'm dizzy, some idea please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get most of what you want with a simple `group_concat()`:

```
select car_num, count(*) as laps, race_id, group_concat(time order by id separator ', ' ) as times
from tiempos t
group by car_num, race_id;
```

If you need the lap number, you can get that using variables:

```
select car_num, count(*) as laps, race_id, group_concat('lap', rn, ' ', time order by id separator ', ' ) as times
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@t = time, @rn + 1,
                        if(@t := time, 1, 1)
                       ) as rn
      from tiempos t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @t := '') vars
      order by race_id, car_num, time
     ) t
group by car_num, race_id;
```

Comment: Why check for `if(@t = time` twice? Shouldn't it just be `if(@t = time, @rn + 1, 1)`?

Comment: @sgeddes . . . You need to do the assignment, and MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`.  So, all the work with the variables is put into one expression.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- but what does `if(@t := time, 1, 1)` solve?  It always evaluates to `1`.  I was just suggesting to consolidate your row number down to `if(@t = time, @rn + 1, 1)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I finally get it!  You've used your `else` criteria to assign the value to `@t` and return 1.  I've always set mine in a separate statement.  +1 for the explanation!